# recount group if out of sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"jumps":[1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,1,1,4,4],
                   "Location":['US','US','US','US','US','US','US','US','US','FR','FR','US','US'], 
                   "job":["sales","sales","sales","marketing","marketing","sales","sales","sales","sales","IT","IT","marketing","marketing"]})
```

result:

```
jumps   Location    job
0   1   US          sales
1   2   US          sales
2   3   US          sales
3   4   US          marketing
4   3   US          marketing
5   2   US          sales
6   1   US          sales
7   2   US          sales
8   3   US          sales
9   1   FR          IT
10  1   FR          IT
11  4   US          marketing
12  4   US          marketing
```

what I wish to do is to group by job based on occurrence. So if the job description is out of sequence - it must be count again. A simple group by job will aggregate sales in the first group and the later group (index 5 to 8).

What I wish to have is the index of the first occurrence:

```
sales 0
marketing 3
sales 5
IT 9
marketing 11
```

Comment: Does 'jumps' have anything to do with this?  Or Location for that matter?  And the title of your question is not what you're actually asking for.  You're looking for the index position of a group, not a count (or recount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
>>> df.reset_index().loc[df['job'].ne(df['job'].shift()), ['job', 'index']]
# or,
>>> df.reset_index().groupby(
       df.job.ne(df.job.shift(1)).cumsum(), as_index=False
    )[['job', 'index']].first()
 
         job  index
0      sales      0
1  marketing      3
2      sales      5
3         IT      9
4  marketing     11
```

Comment: Thanks! and happy to put you in the 10K club (one day maybe for me) ;)

Comment: @ProcolHarum Haha! Thanks! And I'm sure you will get there one day.

Comment: interesting comments

Answer (score 0):

First figure out the indices where `'job'` change:

```
changes = df['job'].ne(df['job'].shift())
```

Then select the rows matching that index:

```
df.loc[changes]
```

output (note the index and the `'job'` column):

```
    jumps Location        job
0       1       US      sales
3       4       US  marketing
5       2       US      sales
9       1       FR         IT
11      4       US  marketing
```